# How to save to different pickles from same python program?

Tags: python, pycharm, pickle, pybrain

Im running multiple PyBrain training runs using the same program but with diff params and saving to a pickle file. 
How would i run the same program but save each instance to a different pickle (preferably without multithreading my program), so i can graph them all in the morning?
Im using PyCharm so i can just run the program multiple times but at the moment it is overwriting the same file
`pickle.dump(nn, open('NN.pkl','wb'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

say you are using parameters a=2, b=3 for a particular run.  write those parameter values into the file name using [format()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec):

```
filename = "NNa{0}b{1}.pk1".format(a,b)
pickle.dump(nn, open(filename,'wb'))
```

will give you a file `NNa2b3.pk1`.

Comment: thanks this sounds good. i was thinking similar with a timestamp, dunno why i didnt think params, im tired :)